# Test Case on Java

Tags: java

How to do test case in Java?? On c++, I can just use while (input--) but does not work on Java?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    //I get error on this line, ita says int can't be converted ro boolean  
    while (n--) {
        if (n < 10) {
            System.out.println(n*n); 
        } else
            System.out.println("enter a number less than 10");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `n-- != 0` ????

Answer (score 3):

Java does not convert from `int`s to `boolean` like C++ does. Instead you have to specify an explicit predicate. Considering this, it would probably be better to use a `for` loop here like this

```
for (int n = sc.nextInt(); n > 0; n--)
    if (n < 10)
        System.out.println(n*n);
    else
        System.out.println("Select a number less than 10");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    while (n > 0) {
        if (n < 10) {
            System.out.println(n*n); 
        } else
            System.out.println("enter a number less than 10");
        }
        n--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

n is declared as an integer. n-- decrements the integer. The while loop requires a boolean, not an integer.